# How do I get the URL of my wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, bluehost

I'm creating a new WordPress blog and have three pages, which I list on the main page.
But when I try and generate links for the text and publish, I get 404 errors.

codewings.blog/about - this is the default page, but I want to link to codewings.blog/webdevelopment, etc.

But wordpress wants to generated page id's in the url.

I don't understand any of this, coming from an ASP.NET background.

Comment: You need to update permalink of your website.

Comment: Thank you. I had to use the page id's in the links as that is how Wordpress seems to work!